# Opera: text-shadow doesn't work inside textarea

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, textarea, opera

I noticed that the text-shadow property doesn't work inside textarea, in Opera.

Any ideas/suggestions ?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/mFKf4/4/)

Comment: doesn't work in `INPUT` as well http://jsfiddle.net/mFKf4/14/

Comment: I would have never though anyone would use text shadow in an input. I guess you have your reasons, but if you're looking for suggestions I'd say get rid of it. No one will be impressed, just annoyed that the text is hard to read (this *is* a form input, right?). At the very least, your 2 Opera users probably won't care :)

Comment: You're right. I've filed a bug.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I recently encountered this problem, and my reason for using text-shadow in an input was specifically to make it easily readable. In my case, to preserve a clean appearance on the website, I wanted the text box to have a transparent background, so I applied a white text-shadow behind it to highlight the text over the background image. Obviously a bug on Opera's part, but I figured I'd share my reason for you, just so you can see there may occasionally be a good reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `o-text-shadow` tag instead.